# Cookies not updating in PHP

Tags: php

Ok I have code that I have used for years and all of a sudden it stopped working and I have no idea how to fix

first I log in and these cookies are set

```
setcookie ("memid", $login->id, strtotime("+1 day"), "/");
setcookie ("package",  $login->package, strtotime("+1 day"), "/");
setcookie ("website",  $login->domain, strtotime("+1 day"), "/");
setcookie ("type",  'main', strtotime("+1 day"), "/");
setcookie ("category",  $login->category, strtotime("+1 day"), "/");
```

This works fine now when I changing something and I update the values

```
setcookie ("website", $_GET['website'], strtotime("+1 day"), "/");
setcookie ("type", $_GET['type'], strtotime("+1 day"), "/");
```

Now instead of updating the values of the previous cookies, it creates new cookies with same name new values.  I assume the first cookies set are still being read because nothing in my app changes.

Even my logout script where I expire the cookies stopped working

```
setcookie('memid', '', time()-1000,"/");
setcookie ("package", '', time()-1000,"/");
setcookie ("website", '', time()-1000,"/");
setcookie ("type", '', time()-1000,"/");
setcookie ("account", '', time()-1000,"/");
setcookie ("permissions", '', time()-1000,"/");
setcookie ("category", '', time()-1000,"/");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you using these commands? There appears to be nothing wrong with how you're actually setting them, but where they're being used could cause a whole plethora of additional issues. You know that you can't access the cookie's value until the next time you reload the page, yes (hopefully)?

Comment: Yeah that is why I am so stumped... it's basic stuff here.. each time I set these I redirect to the page before use... and the odd thing is they worked fine up until last night... same code that has worked for almost two years.  Nothing changed.

Comment: Setting cookie expiry times relative to the server's clock can be hazardous - it presumes the server's and client's clocks are relatively in sync. Best to set an absolute time, like '1' instead. If a user's clock is still in 1970, they deserve whatever pain's coming to them.

Comment: Yeah the time syncs fine.   what about when i set new values and it makes new cookies.   so essentially I have two cookies called website

Comment: @Adam: The only way I see that being possible is if it's storing them under separate domains somehow. Have you tried doing a `die(var_dump($_GET['website']))` to make sure each variable is the intended value?

Comment: Yeah I am using the web dev toolbar in firefox and I can see all the cookies easily.... the one weird thing is I have some set at .domain.com  and then the others are set at dev.domain.com  if I try to set them all to dev.domain.com the ones that are .domain.com become .dev.domain.com

But all cookies are set in the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are setting cookies for a domain like localhost. At least some browsers ignore cookies set for domains that do not have at least one TLD (even if it is invented like .local) and a name before it. So, if you are trying your code under localhost, that may be the problem.